# Formatar centavos em real

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde pessoal.
Estou querendo formatar centavos em real.
Ou seja

`var number = 312311`

virar:

`R$3.123,11`

Mas estou tendo dificuldades. Como faria isso?

Comment: E como você sabe que não é R$ 312,311? Ou R$ 312,311.00?

Comment: Esse valor `312311` são `trezentos e doze mil e trezentos e onze` **centavos**?

Answer (score 1):

O JS já possui por padrão uma função para a formatação de moedas é a [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Um exemplo do uso dela no seu caso.

```
number.toLocaleString("pt-BR", {style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' });
```

Porém vale ressaltar que o `var number = 312311` pode não ser `R$3.123,11` sempre.

Comment: Problema dessa é que ele adiciona ,00 no final e não entende que o meus dois ultimos digitos ja sao os centavos

Comment: Do jeito que você trás os numeros nenhuma funçao vai entender, pois ela pode ser tanto `R$ 312,311` como `R$3.123,11` ou até mesmo como `R$ 312.311,00` que é o retorno da `toLocaleString()`

Comment: Você precisar tratar esse numero antes de utilizar a toLocaleString.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 
      var number = 312311;
      
      var emDecimal = (number/100);
      
      var strString = emDecimal.toString();
      
     //substitui separador decimal ponto por virgula
     strString=strString.replace(".", ",");
     //a regex abaixo coloca um ponto a esquerda de cada grupo de 3 dígitos desde que não seja no inicio do numero
     formatado = strString.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
     
     var resultado ="R$ " + formatado;
     
     document.getElementById('real').innerHTML = resultado;
```

```html
<span id="real"></span>
```